# Limit of a function at its maximum

Tags: calculus, limits, optimization

Let $f_n(x,y)$  be a real function in the domain

$0\leq x\leq 1$

$0\leq y\leq 1$

I would like to compute

$A = \lim_{x \to 0}\left( \arg \max \limits_{y} f(x,y) \right)$,

The problem is that it is not possible to compute analytically $ \arg \max \limits_{y} f(x,y)$. However it is possible to compute

$B= \arg \max \limits_{y} \left( \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,y) \right)$,

Under which conditions $A=B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y^{*}(x) = \arg \max\limits_{y} f(x,y)$. In that case, $y^{*}(x)$ needs to be continuous in x. In that case, the limit of a function is the function of its limit. Otherwise, you can get different answers.